# Wlan unplugs when ethernet connected

Tags: 12.10, wireless, broadcom, ethernet

I own an HP ProBook 4510s Energy Star.
I am connected over WiFi to the internet with a broad-com BCM4312 using the b43 driver.
I am trying to share my Internet connection to a tp-link access point/client in order to connect more devices to the internet.
The problem is that every time i connect the Ethernet cable to my laptop, WiFi, turns off and i cant use it while the Ethernet cable is connected.
My biggest problem is that i cant use WiFi and Ethernet at the same time.
Here is my network hardware and configuration

1st when Ethernet unplugged:

Network:

Card-1: Broadcom BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY driver: b43-pci-bridge

Card-2: Marvell 88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver: sky2

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 18:a9:05:cd:ee:79 
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:1308 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1378 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:338312 (338.3 KB) TX bytes:144517 (144.5 KB)
Interrupt:17 
lo Link encap:Local Loopback 
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
RX packets:1257 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1257 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
RX bytes:38807 (38.8 KB) TX bytes:38807 (38.8 KB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 90:4c:e5:4d:20:96 
inet addr:192.168.1.16 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::924c:e5ff:fe4d:2096/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:407060 errors:0 dropped:7 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:355911 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:451806029 (451.8 MB) TX bytes:42627691 (42.6 MB)
```

2nd when Ethernet plugged:

```
Network:

Card-1: Broadcom BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY driver: b43-pci-bridge 

Card-2: Marvell 88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver: sky2

eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 18:a9:05:cd:ee:79 
inet addr:192.168.1.4 Bcast:192.168.1.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::1aa9:5ff:fecd:ee79/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:1423 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1713 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
RX bytes:346272 (346.2 KB) TX bytes:206229 (206.2 KB)
Interrupt:17 

lo Link encap:Local Loopback 
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
RX packets:1905 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1905 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
RX bytes:59829 (59.8 KB) TX bytes:59829 (59.8 KB)
```

Please inform me if anything else is needed and i will post it as soon as possible.
Thank You and sorry for my English.
Peace

Answer (score 1):

You are using or getting assigned (By a router for example) the same network IP address range for both.

You have the LAN network card (Marvell 88E8072 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet) with the IP: **192.168.1.16**

Then you have your WLAN network card (Broadcom BCM4312 802.11b/g) with the IP: **192.168.1.4**

They can not both be **192.168.1.X**. You need to configure the router that assigns the IP to any of the 2 to assign a different range for one of them. For example, assign the LAN or WLAN the range **192.168.2.X**, so when you have both connected they are in different IP Ranges.

The problem here is that when you have both of them connected and both get, either the same IP address or same IP address range (Assigned from a DHCP Router), the computer thinks you are connecting to the same LAN network and does not know where to get information for the network card, so when you try to send a package, it does not know which network card to use since both point to the same IP range.

Changing the pool of IPs you can assign on one of the network cards will solve the issue. Here is an image of how my router looks on the page where I would change the pool of IPs:

[image]

As you can see, on the section of your Router where it manages the DHCP service (You should have it enabled since you are getting assigned those IP), simply change the IP Address of your router to another range and then change the IPs assigned by DHCP. In this case for example, if I wanted to change this to **192.168.10.X** I would first change the IP Address of the router to the same IP Range I am going to use for the computer, this way I make sure it will be accessible after the changes are made. So I would change where it says **192.168.1.1** to **192.168.10.1**.

Then on the "start IP Address" (It might look different in your Router) I would change the **192.168.1.2** to **192.168.10.2**. Of course in my case it does this last change automatically after changing the Routers IP, but just in case in another Router it does not, then you know which 2 steps to do. Now simply save the new configuration so you can get the new IP assigned to your LAN or WLAN device and enjoy having both network cards working at the same time.